# Ajuda com python requests

Tags: python

Eu quero criar um BOT em python para enviar requisições POST de login, e logo em seguida mandar mais uma requisição para criar personagem, porém quando eu rodo o código ele não cria nenhum personagem, alguém pode me ajudar ?

```
import requests
import random

def gera_char(tamanho):
    caracters = 'abcdefghijlmnopqrstuwvxz'
    senha = ''
    for char in xrange(tamanho):
        senha += random.choice(caracters)
    return senha

login = raw_input("login: ")
password = raw_input("password: ")
#gerador de nome para o char
charname = gera_char(8)

#urls
url_login = 'http://nto-hard.com/?subtopic=accountmanagement'
url_make = 'http://nto-hard.com/?subtopic=accountmanagement&action=createcharacter'
#dados
dados_make = {
        "newcharname": charname,
        "newcharsex": "1",
        "newcharvocation": "29",
        "savecharacter": "1",
        "Submit.x": "52",
        "Submit.y": "12",
        "world": "0"
     }
dados_login = {
        "account_login": login,
        "login.x": "49",
        "login.y": "0",
        "page": "overview",
        "password_login": password
    }

requests.post(url_login, data=dados_login)
requests.post(url_make, data=dados_make)
```

Comment: Você não precisa utilizar a resposta na requisição de login para conseguir fazer a segunda? Como a segunda requisição sbaerá que você já fez o login?

Comment: Não tenho como testar, mas o comentário acima está mais ou menos no caminho; você precisa salvar as informações de sessão (cookies) do login. Pra isso, crie uma instância de requests.Session e chame as funções post dela, ao invés de como está fazendo. (`s = requests.Session()`, `s.post(...)`.

Comment: Eu pensava exatamente nos cookies, mas não sei usar o requests muito bem... vou pesquisar sobre

Comment: A menos que você queira realmente aprender a usar requests e como as coisas funcionam te aconselharia a usar o [selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/). Fora isso ainda é possível utilizar a [extensão de para o Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-BR/firefox/addon/selenium-ide/) e com base nas ações que você executa no browser exportar o código equivalente em Python.

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente os sites vão ler a data do seu request no formato json e você não esta enviando ela neste formato, para transforma-lo importe a biblioteca [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) assim:

```
import json
```

E depois mude as duas ultimas linhas para que ele envie a data no formato json:

```
requests.post(url_login, data=json.dumps(dados_login))
requests.post(url_make, data=json.dumps(dados_make))
```

---

Se não funcionar tente dar uma olhada nos cookies e no header do requests